# -bash: /usr/bin/psql: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, psql, fedora, permission-denied

I get the above error message when I try to run psql commands.

I used the following method to install postgresql on my computer: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-fedora/

When I try to run it the command with `sudo`, I am prompted to give a password which I have no idea what could be for postgres user.

---

[pedro@fedora ~]$ sudo su - postgres

[sudo] password for pedro:

[postgres@fedora ~]$ sudo psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'password'"

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

[sudo] password for postgres:

sudo: a password is required

---

The command that produces the error is the following:

`psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'StrongPassword'"`

It can be found in the tutorial (the page I referenced in the beginning). I did all the preceding commands and all of them have completed successfully.

Any idea what the solution can be?

Comment: Prompted how? Because `sudo` will be asking you for the system password so it can run "whatever follows it" with elevated permissions. It should not be asking for the postgres user's credentials (unless you're running `sudo` with `-u` to explicitly say which system user account it should be running the rest of the command as)

Comment: I edited the question to show that part of the terminal.

Comment: What do you see for `ls -l /usr/bin/psql`?

Comment: What do you see for `file /usr/bin/psql` ?

Comment: Your mistake is not following the instructions you link to. This is the problem : `sudo psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'password'"`. At that point you are already the `postgres` user all you have to do is run:`psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'password'"`. Which is exactly how the the instructions you linked to show it.

Comment: I thought so, but when I use the command without `sudo`, I get the following:
-bash: /usr/bin/psql: Permission denied

Comment: @jjanes
I get the following:
ls -l /usr/bin/psql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 74 Oct 23 01:26 /usr/bin/psql -> /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2128/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psql

Comment: @wildplasser
And the other command gives this:
[postgres@fedora ~]$ file /usr/bin/psql
/usr/bin/psql: symbolic link to /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2128/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psql

Comment: So `Snap` has hijacked the `psql` binary.  I have no idea on how undo that safely.  You will probably need to search for an answer or create a new question.

Comment: What is the cause exactly? What do I need to eliminate?

Comment: That is the way how RedHat manages installed binaries and access to them. It puts a shellscript in /usr/bin/ that checks the authorisation and then (maybe) calls the actual binary.

Comment: Well that is weird.  The instructions install it with dnf, not with snap.  So it looks like before you followed those instructions, you had done something else first which interfered with it.